# CentOs 7 WMCS displaying a 500 http error. Was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.6 and cannot run under PHP 7.1

Tags: php, apache, whmcs, ioncube

I migrated my WHMCS from a virtual machine to a full centos running machine, i am experiencing trouble when trying to view any on the WHMCS directory. It displays a

> This page isn’t working
>
> 192.168.1.4 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

I went into SSH and viewed the /var/log/httpd/error_log to find a relevant error.

```
**[Sun Oct 29 09:51:43.886770 2017] [php7:error] [pid 5951] [client 192.168.1.8:25937] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/client/index.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.6 and cannot run under PHP 7.1.\n Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for PHP 7.1. in Unknown on line 0**
```

The confusing thing is, i am running ioncube 7.1 on php 7.1. But for some reason the server does not think so.

I did a php -v

```
    [root@new-host-7 ~]# php -v
PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2017 10:30:04) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
```

In my php.ini file i told it it to use ioncube 7.1 :

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so
```

And if i create a info.php page on my webserver i receive a successful response:

```
PHP Version 7.1.10
```

What is causing the log to say that i am using different versions?

Answer (score 0):

From WHMCS [System Requirements](https://docs.whmcs.com/System_Requirements) page: WHMCS 7.x supports PHP 5.6 and 7.0

You'll need to use PHP 7.0.X for WHMCS to work.

Comment: i am using php 7.1 hence 'PHP Version 7.1.10', i even said.

Comment: No, use 7.0, not 7.1. They are different branches.

Comment: PHP 7 begins properly at PHP 7.1, with significant changes internally between 7.0 and 7.1, which is why PHP 5.6 files cannot be supported on 7.1. WHMCS can produce files for PHP 7.1 though, so just ask them for a PHP 7.1 build or else drop down to 7.0 as @wesamly suggested.